# read a vcs from url in javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to read a vcs file like this one:

http://ziggi.bgu.co.il/outlook.php?user=sample@email.com
if you click on that link it will download a vcs file, then if you open it with notepad you get something like:

```
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:WebSched
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
```

...

what I want is to be able to get thouse lines from that url(i do not hold that domain),
and read them line by line.
and I need it in javascript or php code.

Answer (score 0):

You will not easily be able to do it in pure JavaScript due to cross-domain restrictions. However, it is doable in PHP.

Your server will most likely have fopen wrappers enabled, which allow you to use stream wrappers (http, ftp, ssh etc) on common file functions.
    file()
in particular, returns an array of lines in a file.

Combine both together:

```
 $arrayOfLines = file("http://ziggi.bgu.co.il/outlook.php?user=yoav.hops@gmail.com");
```

And your $arrayOfLines suddenly contains all the lines in the file, and you're now free to iterate over them as you please! Before you do this, though, make sure to check that $arrayOfLines is an array - as it will not be if the file failed to load.